# Firestore authorization for Google Compute engine for app on a docker container

Tags: firebase, docker, google-cloud-firestore, google-compute-engine

I have deployed a Node.js app on a Google compute instance via a Docker container. Is there a recommended way to pass the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the docker container?

I see the documentation states that GCE has Application Default Credentials (ADC), but these are not available in the docker container. (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

I am a bit new to docker & GCP, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, I could find this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local#running_locally_using_docker_with_access_to_services) on where you can inject your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS into a docker in order to test cloud run locally, I know that this is not cloud run, but I believe that the same command could be used in order to inject your credentials to the container.

As I know that a lot of the times the community needs the steps and commands as the links could change and information also could change I will copy the steps needed in order to inject the credentials.

> 1. Refer to [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for instructions
>      on generating, retrieving, and configuring your Service Account
>      credentials.
> 2. The following Docker run flags inject the credentials and
>      configuration from your local system into the local container:
>
>    - Use the --volume (-v) flag to inject the credential file into the
>        container (assumes you have already set your
>        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable on your machine):
>
> `-v $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json:ro`
>
> - Use the --environment (-e) flag to set the
>     GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable inside the container:
>
> `-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json`
>
> Optionally, use this fully configured Docker run command:
>
> ```
> PORT=8080 && docker run \
>  -p 9090:${PORT} \
>  -e PORT=${PORT} \
>  -e K_SERVICE=dev \
>  -e K_CONFIGURATION=dev \
>  -e K_REVISION=dev-00001 \
>  -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json \
>  -v $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json:ro \ gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE
> ```
>
> Note that the path
>
> `/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json`
>
> shown in the example above is a reasonable location to place your
>   credentials inside the container. However, other directory locations
>   will also work. The crucial requirement is that the
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable must match the
>   bind mount location inside the container.

Hope this works for you.